# Let $p(z) = az^n + z + 1$, $n \ge 2$ and $a \in \Bbb{C}$. Show that $p(z)$ has a root in the disc $|z| \le 2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $p(z) = az^n + z + 1$, $n \ge 2$ and $a \in \Bbb{C}$. Show that $p(z)$ has a root in the disc $|z| \le 2$.

I have thrown the book at this problem and have no idea how to proceed. The general plan of attack is to apply the argument principle and evaluate $\int_{|z| = 2} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} dz$, but since we can't assume anything about any poles located inside the contour it seems difficult to apply usual complex analytic methods, and the integral appears impossible to directly calculate. It is easy to see that if $|a| > 2^{-n}$ then the statement holds, since 1 is equal to $a$ times the product of all roots (up to multiplication by -1).

Comment: Your proposed integral will be zero if there is no root, right? And nonzero if there is.

Comment: Another track: have you seen Rouché's theorem ? See for example (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1769515).

Comment: I have not seen Rouche's theorem, so a solution without it would be preferable. I know that it is sufficient to show the integral does not vanish, but even this is so far beyond me.

Comment: Since $a$ is arbitrary, could induction on $n$ be useful somehow? I mean, the inductive step will be $az^{n+1} + z+1 = bz^n +z +1$ for $b=az$. So by hypotesis, this polynomial has a root in the disc.

Comment: @Luis since $b$ is not a constant your inductive hypothesis doesn't really say anything about $bz^n + z + 1$.

Comment: @JeanMarie there appear to be problems with Rouche's theorem since $a$ is arbitrary.

Comment: We don't need to compute the proposed integral directly. We only need to show it is nonzero.

Comment: Now I'm pretty sure it works. Let me put it in another way. If $a=0$ there's nothing to prove. Now, for $a\ne 0$, pick any solution of $az^{n-1} +z +1$ inside the disc (induction hypotesis) Choose the unique $b$ such that $bz=a$ and then you are constructing a solution for $bz^n +z+1$ in the disc.

Comment: @abnry I understand that. As I said, I have had no luck even showing it is nonzero.

Comment: @Luis I think you might have a point. I'm gonna look it over closely and see if it works out.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work by induction

Comment: @Luis I don't think it works out. You would need to be able to write any $b \in \Bbb{C}$ as $b = \frac{a}{r}$, where $a$ is arbitrary and $ar^{n-1} + r + 1 = 0$. Since $r$ depends on $a$ this appears unlikely to me, and almost definitely highly nontrivial to prove.

Comment: Now I see where I was wrong. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: Do you think that the problems you are speaking about vanish if one divides the polynomial by $a$ (operation that doesn't change the roots) ?

Comment: Well, we managed to get it using a combination of Rouche's theorem and my observation, as explained below. I haven't worked it out but I imagine dividing by $a$ would not really change things enough to allow you to use only Rouche's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply Rouché for $|a|<2^{-n}$ (since $|az^n|<1\leq |1+z|$ for $|z|=2$) and your argument with the root product for $|a|>2^{-n}$ to show that in both cases there is at least one root in the open disk of radius 2. By continuity there is at least one on the closed disk when $|a|=2^{-n}$. Note that $1+z+z^2/4=0$ shows that the radius 2 is optimal.

Comment: Very nice-- I just needed to put the pieces together. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you extend the answer by showing how to apply Rouché for $|a|<2^{-n}$?

Comment: Actually using Rouché is enough. Suppose all the roots are outside the $|z| \le 2$ disk. Then, using Vieta, one gets $|a|<2^{-n}$, impossible because of Rouché theorem

Comment: Well, I think that was the point in the root product argument (except we didn't put a name on it).

Comment: That being said, I imagine there's another way to solve this since it was a homework problem and we haven't seen Rouche's theorem yet.

Comment: Yes, it seems a bit advanced given your description  above. So depends on your teacher : If you have learned about the argument principle, that it takes integer values (* $2\pi i$) and varies continuously with $a$ (when non-vanishing on the circle) then perhaps your teacher thinks that you may deduce the result that way (i.e. in fact proving Rouché by hand). But agree, it may be beyond what your teacher had in mind.